# error in deploying react-native app on android device

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i am getting an error in starting up react native app on my android device
i install `node.js`,`react-native cli` and every thing which is required for `react native`.

Please help me to solve this

[image: command prompt screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

**Please Make sure your device is connected with system where you want to install the build or run your app**

you might check the permissions on android/gradlew

they should be 755 not 644

run chmod 755 android/gradlew inside your app root folder
then run react-native run-android

and it should work again.